# Help with Browser detection code

Tags: php

I have a problem with the line 36 of this code.

```
<?PHP
class Browser
{
    private $props    = array("Version" => "0.0.0",
                                "Name" => "unknown",
                                "Agent" => "unknown") ;

    public function __Construct()
    {
        $browsers = array("firefox", "msie", "opera", "chrome", "safari",
                            "mozilla", "seamonkey",    "konqueror", "netscape",
                            "gecko", "navigator", "mosaic", "lynx", "amaya",
                            "omniweb", "avant", "camino", "flock", "aol");

        $this->Agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        foreach($browsers as $browser)
        {
            if (preg_match("#($browser)[/ ]?([0-9.]*)#", $this->Agent, $match))
            {
                $this->Name = $match[1] ;
                $this->Version = $match[2] ;
                break ;
            }
        }
    }

    public function __Get($name)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->props))
        {
            die "No such property or function $name" ;
        }
        return $this->props[$name] ;
    }

    public function __Set($name, $val)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->props))
        {
            SimpleError("No such property or function.", "Failed to set $name", $this->props) ;
            die ;
        }
        $this->props[$name] = $val ;
    }

}

?>
```

this is the line that have the error  `die "No such property or function $name" ;` any help would be appropriated.

Comment: I use: get_browser @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: I'm curios, what is the error?

Comment: Do you really want the PHP script to die() when a property of a class is not found and not throw an exception? And why don't you just create public properties `Name` and `Version`?

Comment: Do you really want to add browser detection to PHP? It is Very Complex and never completely right. There are many libraries that try to do this, but no one is perfect. You better leave browser detection, or rather: functionality detection to the client side code.

Comment: They just suggested me this http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/ in another question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line needs to be this, instead:

```
die("No such property or function $name");
```

See [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you rewrite that code to this?:

```
<?php

class Browser
{

    public $Version = "0.0.0";
    public $Name = "unknown";
    public $Agent = "unknown";

    public function __Construct()
    {
        $browsers = array("firefox", "msie", "opera", "chrome", "safari",
                            "mozilla", "seamonkey",    "konqueror", "netscape",
                            "gecko", "navigator", "mosaic", "lynx", "amaya",
                            "omniweb", "avant", "camino", "flock", "aol");

        $this->Agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        foreach($browsers as $browser)
        {
            if (preg_match("#($browser)[/ ]?([0-9.]*)#", $this->Agent, $match))
            {
                $this->Name = $match[1] ;
                $this->Version = $match[2] ;
                break ;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Anyways, I suggest you using some already-existing library to detect browser, like http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/